# Not able to start MySQL in UBUNTU 18`

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

This might be old one. But I have tried many solutions. If I can not fix now, I will loose my databases.

Please help. I have attached screen shot

**Suddenly MySQL stopped and I am getting this type of error, when going to start again**

[image: This is screen of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo see the logs? Usually in the logs says something about the problem.
/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
in the logs you can see all about your server. Good Day!

Comment: great. You have opened my eyes. I have fixed it. Changed memory allocation value. innodb_buffer_pool_size=100M in my.cnf file

Comment: Good to help you!